# Error when trying to coerce date format in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe  as follows with date in the following format

dataframe - housedat

```
date     time power voltage intensity  SM1 SM2 SM3 NA
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00 4.216   0.418    234.84 18.4   0   1 17
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00 5.360   0.436    233.63 23.0   0   1 16
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00 5.374   0.498    233.29 23.0   0   2 17
4 16/12/2006 17:27:00 5.388   0.502    233.74 23.0   0   1 17
5 16/12/2006 17:28:00 3.666   0.528    235.68 15.8   0   1 17
6 16/12/2006 17:29:00 3.520   0.522    235.02 15.0   0   2 17
```

I am trying to coerce the dataframe with the following command

```
housedat$date <- as.Date(housedat$date,"%d/%m/%y")
```

However, the result which I am getting is as follows, which is not what I expected

```
 date     time power voltage intensity  SM1 SM2 SM3 NA
1 2020-12-16 17:24:00 4.216   0.418    234.84 18.4   0   1 17
2 2020-12-16 17:25:00 5.360   0.436    233.63 23.0   0   1 16
3 2020-12-16 17:26:00 5.374   0.498    233.29 23.0   0   2 17
4 2020-12-16 17:27:00 5.388   0.502    233.74 23.0   0   1 17
5 2020-12-16 17:28:00 3.666   0.528    235.68 15.8   0   1 17
6 2020-12-16 17:29:00 3.520   0.522    235.02 15.0   0   2 17
```

There is no year "2020" in the whole data frame and all the dates are appearing in the above format.

Any suggestions on what to be done ??

Comment: Your format should be `"%d/%m/%Y"` with a capital Y for 4-digit year

Comment: or strptime(housedat$date,format="%d/%m/%Y)

Comment: @linp that would create a `POSIXlt`, not a `Date`

Comment: @Gsee you are right. :) I thought he/she wants to keep the hour/min/sec.